# Why does replacing an output variable after second for loop change the output in this for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to programming and learn Python as my first language. I try to debug this code to understand how it works. But I can only understand the code 50%. I have doubt here why I can not replace (output empty variable) after second for loop (in range loop) to get same output. But If I do that, It becomes different output. Please help me to understand this code.

```
numbers = [5,2,5,2,2]
for x_count in numbers:
    output = ''
    for count in range(x_count):
        #output = ''
        output = output + 'x'
    print(output)

xxxxx
xx
xxxxx
xx
xx
```

I need to understand this code

Comment: Just step through it line by line.  Is there a specific line whose effect is confusing?  If you’re having trouble following how your code relates to the output, try adding something like `print(f"starting inner loop for {x_count} with output={output}")` before your inner `for` loop.

Comment: If you assign an empty string to `output`, then **of course** you will not get the same results.  Frankly I don't even understand the question...

Comment: This website can help you visualize your code and run it step by step: https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Again, Specially my heartful thanks to @Samwise Love your approach. Finally, got it.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [5,2,5,2,2]
for x_count in numbers:          #create a loop for each value in 'numbers'
    output = ''                  #declare variable
    for count in range(x_count): #next loop, where 'range' make 'x_count' cycles 
        #output = ''             #do nothing, but if it works. then on each cycle it will re-declare a variable, which means deleting its previous value 
        output = output + 'x'    #add 'x' on each cycle 'next loop'
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

numbers = [5,2,5,2,2]
for x_count in numbers:
output = ''
for count in range(x_count):
#output = ''
output = output + 'x'
print(output)

I found the answer for my question. Here is the answer. When I mention output empty string variable after second inner loop, the inner loop repeatedly make output with 'x to the only one 'x. That means, when inner for loops runs over the range of first number from numbers list, for example :(0,1,2,3,4) the the output variable with 'x' only becomes one 'x'. Because the output empty variable change the range of number into only one 'x. That's why It shows only one 'x' 5 times in column. check the output below.

output :

```
x
x
x
x
x
```